# Remove data in csv after _ characters per cell python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that has some info inside of it. For my use case, I only need the first four characters in every cell.

So, using python, I need a solution that will allow me ideally to remove all characters in each cell after four characters, and optionally remove all spaces. If I could be pointed in the correct direction that'd be great!

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OneOneOne | TwoTwoTwo | ThreeThreeThree |

My Ideal output should look like

| one | two | three |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OneO | TwoT | Thre |

Comment: kindly provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is a very easy problem.  Show us your code and explain what isn't working.

Comment: The normal way to get the prefix of a string is `prefix = mystring[0:4]`.

Comment: `df.agg(lambda x:x.str[0:4])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your data contains some numeric values not of string type.  In that case, you can convert the data to string first, then remove all spaces, and finally take the first 4 characters in each converted strings, as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")       # read csv if not already read

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(' ', '').str[0:4])

df.to_csv("mycsv.csv")             # save to csv
```

If you don't need to remove spaces, you can use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")       # read csv if not already read

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str[0:4])

df.to_csv("mycsv.csv")             # save to csv
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)


    one   two three
0  OneO  TwoT  Thre
```

### Edit

If you want to apply to only specify columns, you can use:

For example, only apply to columns `one` and `two`:

```
df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")       # read csv if not already read

df[['one', 'two']] = df[['one', 'two']].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.replace(' ', '').str[0:4])

df.to_csv("mycsv.csv")             # save to csv
```

Comment: This runs without issue, but doesn't appear to actually effect the csv file whatsoever.

Comment: you need to save the dataframe as csv if you want the change to be saved permanently in the file

Comment: @JeremyGorden  You can further save it to csv.  See my edit for sample code.

Comment: @SreeramTP I see, thanks! Is there any way to apply this only to specific columns?

Comment: @JeremyGorden  See my edit for applying to specific columns.  You don't need looping on the columns.  Just use the selected columns all at a time.

Comment: Thank you so much. One last thing, I hope you don't mind-I figured this would work forward and back, for instance if I wanted to get the last 4 characters instead of the first as we've done here.

I figured I'd flip the [0:4] and make it [4:0] and it'd work, but apparently it doesn't?

Comment: @JeremyGorden  You can use `[-4:]` to get the last 4 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Adapting the answer by @SeaBean to show how to apply to just selected columns,

```
df = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")       # read csv if not already read
cols = ['col_1', 'col_2'] # cols to apply

for col in cols:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str[0:4])

df.to_csv("mycsv.csv")             # save to csv
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better way, but I think this could get you started:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv")

# remove spaces and keep first four letters
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '')[:4])
```

---

Update to account for non-string columns. This only changes string columns. If you want to truncate numbers also, others answers have covered that.

```
import pandas as pd

file = "myfile.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file)

# select only columns of type str
cols = (df.applymap(type) == str).all(0)

# first 4 letters of each cell
first_four_no_space = lambda x: x.replace(' ', '')[:4]
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].applymap(first_four_no_space)

# Warning! This will overwrite your existing file.
# I would rename the output, but it sounds like you want to
# overwrite. Uncomment if you want to overwrite your existing
# file.
# df.to_csv(file, index=False)
```

Comment: I've tried this but I'm getting AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace''

Comment: I've updated my answer to account for non-sting columns. The update selects only string columns to truncate. You might want to update your question as it does not currently reflect your actual data structure.